# ArcMap report designer dataset options

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, reports, template

It has been a while since I have messed with the dataset options in the report designer. In the past I was able to set the dataset options to run reports on the current date and leave it like that within the report template.

The advantage to that is that anyone could run the report and it would generate results for that day.

However, I can't seem to remember the correct syntax. It was something like

`Date = CURRENTDATE()`

But that does not work and it will not verify.

Can someone please show me the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good source of information [Adding report page numbers or dates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/reports/adding-report-page-numbers-or-dates.htm) from Esri, to add the date to your report.

> Add page numbers or dates to your report to make your report easier to interpret. Page numbers give context to the entire report in terms of how much content there is; dates allow the target audience to understand what point in time the report references.

[image]

> Open a report in the Report Designer.
>   Under Design Elements, click ReportInfo.
>   Drag the ReportInfo element into the section where you want the page number or date displayed.
>   Under Element Properties, change the FormatString property.
>   Choose from the list of available page formats and dates.
>   Click the ellipsis (…) button on the Font property to display the Font dialog box.
>   Choose the font, style, and size for the page number.